# JavaFX8 fxml naming of nested controllers

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Given an .fxml include like:

```
<fx:include fx:id="header" source="Header.fxml" />
```

The Java [FXML docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) say to create two variables like:

```
@FXML private HBox header;
@FXML private HeaderController headerController;
```

What determines the controller variable name? Is it *always* just the include id followed by "Controller"?

Comment: It's not explicitly stated in the documentation, but that is how I interpret it (and it always seems to work that way.)

Comment: What better way is there to identify which controller is associated with the fxml file?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson something like header.getController() and a variable name I can control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the field name the controller is injected to is always constructed by concatenating the `fx:id` of the `<fx:include>` tag with `"Controller"`.

It's "hidden" in the documentation of [the `FXMLLoader.CONTROLLER_SUFFIX` field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#CONTROLLER_SUFFIX).

> A suffix for controllers of included fxml files. The full key is stored in namespace map.

*(The namespace map contains all the objects by the field name they are injected to, if such a field exists.)*

You can verify that it's value is `"Controller"` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/constant-values.html#javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.CONTROLLER_SUFFIX

Comment: Very comprehensive answer! Thank you.