# Javafx: link fx:id-s

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have a UI with many components which could be *reused* ; so, I have a few `.fxml` files linked. My parent .fxml embeds this:

```
<fx:include source="Child.fxml" fx:id="first">
<fx:include source="Child.fxml" fx:id="second">
```

The `Child.fxml` looks like this:

```
<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <Label fx:id="label"/>
    <ComboBox fx:id="comboBox"/>
    <TextField fx:id="firstTextfield"/>
    <TableView fx:id="secondTextfield"/>
</HBox>
```

The `Parent.fxml` has a defined `fx:controller="ParentController"`. The question is, how can I set/get the data for each individual child in parent.
like:

```
first.getLabel().setText("This is the first Label");
first.getComboBox().getValue();
second.getLabel().setText("This is the second Label");
...
```

**Please don't suggest as answer** `fist.getChildren().get(0)` **and others similar methods.**

I know I can define only one big `.fxml`, and then give every single item an id, but I want to avoid to duplicate code, and I want to split them in a smaller components so it may become more understandable, and I can reuse them.

Comment: Does the children have their own controllers ? if so, you can just instantiate in the parent controller the children controllers.

Comment: @Calips "Instantiate the parent controller"?? It won't help to instantiate the controller: you would have a different instance than the one created when the FXML was loaded.

Comment: @James_D "instantiate **in** the parent controller" still wrong what i said ? or maybe "Decalre" not instantiate lol

Comment: @James_D I think this is exactly what Sunflame is trying to achieve : from the `ParentController` class/instance being able to instantiate/use the `Parent` view and therefore `Child` view as well. So, the method proposed by @Calips could be a workaround.

Comment: Yes. It is never useful to "instantiate a controller" (which doesn't even really make sense: you instantiate a class - a controller is a specific object, not a class) unless you are providing it to the `setController` method of the `FXMLLoader` (which is not possible in this scenario). You need the actual controller already created: it does not help to create a new instance of the controller class (assuming that is what you meant).

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the explanation :D i meant by instantiate "Declaring" my bad XD sorry

Comment: @Paradox What do you mean by "instantiate/use"? Those are completely different things. Creating a new instance of a controller class will never be a "workaround": all the `@FXML`-injected fields will be null.

Comment: Yes, I know these are 2 differents concepts ; I never meant creating a **new** instance of the controller. I meant declaring Child(s)Controller inside the ParentController.

Comment: And now that you posted your answer, this is exactly what I was thinking about, even if Controller to Controller communication is should "at the very least" be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the controllers for the included FXML into the controller for the FXML that is including them:

```
public class ParentController {

    @FXML
    private ChildController firstController ; 
    @FXML
    private ChildController secondController ;

    @FXML
    private Pane childContainer ; // container holding the included FXMLs

    // ...
}
```

Here I am assuming that `Child.fxml` declares a controller class `fx:controller="ChildController"`. The rule for naming the fields for the [nested controllers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) is that they are the [`fx:id` of the included FXML with `"Controller"` appended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467982/javafx8-fxml-naming-of-nested-controllers).

Define the appropriate data methods in that controller (it is generally bad practice to allow direct access to the controls themselves):

```
public class ChildController {

    @FXML
    private Label label ;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> comboBox ;

    // etc...

    public void setDisplayText(String text) {
        label.setText(text);
    }

    public String getUserSelectedValue() {
        return comboBox.getValue();
    }

    // ...
}
```

And now back in the `ParentController` all you need is

```
first.setDisplayText("This is the first Label");
first.getUserSelectedValue();
second.setDisplayText("This is the second Label");
```

etc.

If you need to include more instances of the FXML defined in `Child.fxml` dynamically at runtime, you just need:

```
// modify resource name as needed:
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Child.fxml"));
Parent childUI = loader.load();
ChildController childController = loader.getController();
childContainer.getChildren().add(childUI);
```

Comment: That's what i meant :c

Comment: @James_D thanks probably this is the solution, one question remains open for me, do the children controllers implement `Initializable`, or the components will be initialized anyway?

Comment: @Sunflame Controllers have not had to implement `Initializable` since JavaFX v2.1

Comment: One more question, can I use this solution for adding components dynamic, for example if the number of child depend on some variable, can I use this for adding them somehow from `ParentController` or not?

Comment: @Sunflame Sure. That's really a different question and I don't know where you are stuck. To add child nodes dynamically, just load the FXML in the usual way and get the controller from the `FXMLLoader`. I added some sample code.

Comment: Exactly that is I want. Thank you very much.