# Error when trying to pass a variable to another controller in javafx/scenebuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making a simple program wherein I am trying to add a string from a TextField to a ListView in another scene. The problem is I am getting a NullPointerException when I pass the string to the method which will add it to the List.

Here is the code for controller for the main scene:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainPageController {

@FXML TextField txtfield;

public void addButton(ActionEvent event) {

    String a=txtfield.getText();
    FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/progra/view/ListView.fxml"));
    ListController obj=loader.getController();
    obj.addList(a);// <----NullPointerException

}

public void openList(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/program /view/ListView.fxml"));
    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
    stage.show();

}
}
```

Here is the code for the controller of the list scene:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class ListController{

@FXML
ListView<String> listofstrs;

public void addList(String a) {

    listofstrs.getItems().add(a);

}
}
```

What do I need to do to fix it? If I may add, is it possible to add variables to a ListView (or any other text containers) in another stage/scene without opening the stage/scene where it is contained, and when you open it you will see the things you added? If so, what do i need to add?

Comment: Which line is throwing the `NullPointerException`?  And are you sure your `FXML` defines a `ListView` named `listofstrs`?

On a side note, please learn the Java naming conventions and stick to them (object references should be camel-cased: `listOfStrs`). It helps us help you :)

Comment: obj.addList(a);

Comment: Then clearly your `obj` object is `null`. Did you define a controller using the `fx:controller` tag in your `ListView.fxml` file?

Comment: Nope...How do you do that and what do you mean?
Edit: Yes I did through SceneBuilder

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but everytime I have use this approach I call `loader.load();` somewhere before `loader.getController();`.

Comment: Oh my it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling the `getController()` method, and the controller is not set within the Java source, you must have the controller defined within your fxml file. Can you post the fxml source?

In your fxml, your root element should have the fx:controller attribute set to the class path of the controller, e.g:

`fx:controller="com.class.path.to.ListController`

Comment: Neither of your points is correct, I'm afraid. The controller class can be named anything you'd like. Also, you can call `getController()` on any loader object, whether the controller was defined in FXML or using the `setController()` method. (Though in the OP's case, you are correct, just not generally speaking)

Comment: I removed the downvote, but this should still be a comment, not an answer, since you are asking for more information :)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I skipped over the reason why the controller must be defined in the FXML. Regarding the naming controller convention, I was conflating this method of obtaining the controller instance with using an @FXML annotation, which does require specific class names https://stackoverflow.com/a/44470823/9197327

Comment: Interesting. I've never run into an issue with that, but I've also never used `fx:include` in my projects. Good info :)